# Loading Scripts Sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a web page that I Load my scripts sequentially because each loaded script needs the script loaded before it. For example `js/global.js`, `js/menu.js`, `js/loan.js` and `js/contribution.js` in that order need each other, `contributions.js` need `loan.js`, `loan,js` needs `menu.js`, and so on. I have managed to achieve this with the code below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

LoadScriptscontri();
});

function LoadScriptscontri(async) {
    if (async === undefined) {
        async = false;
    }
    var scripts = [];
    var _scripts = [  'js/global.js', 'js/menu.js', 'js/loan.js', 'js/contributions.js'];

    if (async) {
        LoadScriptsAsync(_scripts, scripts)
    } else {
        LoadScriptsSync(_scripts, scripts)
    }
}

    // what you are looking for :
   function LoadScriptsSync(_scripts, scripts) {

    var x = 0;
    var loopArray = function (_scripts, scripts) {
        // call itself
        loadScript(_scripts[x], scripts[x], function () {
            // set x to next item
            x++;
            // any more items in array?
            if (x < _scripts.length) {
                loopArray(_scripts, scripts);
            }
        });
    }
    loopArray(_scripts, scripts);
}

// async load as in your code
function LoadScriptsAsync(_scripts, scripts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < _scripts.length; i++) {
        loadScript(_scripts[i], scripts[i], function () { });
    }
}

// load script function with callback to handle synchronicity 
function loadScript(src, script, callback) {

    script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onerror = function () {
        // handling error when loading script
        alert('Error to handle')
    }
    script.onload = function () {
        console.log(src + ' loaded ')
        callback();
    }
    script.src = src;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

but he problem is when ever I change page using `window.location = "http://cooperative-izumedia.rhcloud.com/contributions.html";` maybe from this to `window.location = "http://cooperative-izumedia.rhcloud.com/dashboard.html";` and back it no longer loads in the required order instead `contributions.js` is loaded first. What exactly is happening and how do I get rid of this. I tested it in both firefox and chrome and I still get the same results.

My debugging Info

> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/global.js loaded
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/menu.js loaded
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/loan.js loaded
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/dashboard.js loaded
>
> menu.js:113 id in menu.js = d2b2aecb0197b6f439056 `/*here am spitting out the id got from menu.js*/`
>
> dashboard.js:119 0 `/*here dashboard.js is able to determine that the section it will work on is of index 0 thanks to menu.js*/`
>
> Navigated to http://cooperative-izumedia.rhcloud.com/contributions.html`/*here I change page*/`
>
> contributionsjsloader.js:54 js/global.js loaded
>
> contributionsjsloader.js:54 js/menu.js loaded
>
> contributionsjsloader.js:54 js/loan.js loaded
>
> contributions.js:71 Contri something `/*For some reason menu.js isnt't called to spit out its value before contribution.js tell us something even before contibution.js is loaded which loaded below*/`
>
> contributionsjsloader.js:54 js/contributions.js loaded
>
> menu.js:183 can't make index TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeAttribute' of undefined `/*Now menu.js decides to show its face and this exception is allowed, its expected.*/`
>
> menu.js:113 id in menu.js = d2b2aecb0197b6f439056 `/* and then it finally spits out its value*/`
>
> Navigated to http://cooperative-izumedia.rhcloud.com/dashboard.html
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/global.js loaded
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/menu.js loaded
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/loan.js loaded
>
> dashboardjsloader.js:54 js/dashboard.js loaded
>
> `/* I go back to dashboard and because menu is not called first my dashboard.js goes to complete shits */`
>
> dashboard.js:119 NaN
>
> dashboard.js:132 TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined
>
> dashboard.js:75 in dashboard TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of 
>   undefined
>
> `/*Now menu.js rears its ugly head*/`
>
> menu.js:113 id in menu.js = d2b2aecb0197b6f439056

Comment: Script injected scripts are async by default. Try adding `script.async = false` in your loadScript function.

Comment: @SalmanA: See the code above, the OP is clearly waiting for the previous script to finish loading before loading the next.

Comment: Alex - *"What exactly is happening and how do I get rid of this. I tested it in both firefox and chrome and I still get the same results."* What do you see when you use the fully-featured debugger built into your browser? What kinds of debugging have you done? This question comes down to "Please debug this code for me" right now. That's really something for you to do, and then if you still have a question, post a question about the details you've found.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder he is simply appending a couple of `<script>` elements in head. As far as I remember, they are async by default.

Comment: Separately: You're using jQuery's `ready` event to asynchronously load scripts in series. Why? That's a **lot** of work to replicate what the browser does for you: Just put your scripts in standard script tags at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag, [as is the usual recommendation](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom). They will load behind the scenes, in order, without blocking display of your page, without blocking the firing of `ready`, and will have full access to all of the elements on your page.

Comment: @SalmanA: Look at the code. He's waiting to append the next until the previous finishes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have done the debugging. if you look at my code, I console out the each file that is load as it is loaded and they appear in the preferred but for some reason the last js file is called second before the `menu.js` after I leave the page and then come back again.

Comment: @alexdavies try adding a line at the end of each script reading `script x loaded`. I am sure the scripts are executed in random order... whichever downloads faster or loaded from cache wins.

Comment: I'd just merge the files together (specific order = broken code and/or wrong subdivision)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I started with that before having it just at the end of my body tag but I get the same result. only that then on refresh `contributions.js` load before `menu.js` but on refresh again t goes back to it normal order. but with this new code style on first refresh it follows the order I want but on next refresh or change of page and back  , it messes up the order.

Comment: @alexdavies: That would have to be observational error. As The Pragmatic Programmer says, "`select` isn't broken." Neither is script loading in browsers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay you know what I would share the link to the site with you and you can test it yourself, I will place alert boxes in each js file to show you the order in which it loads. any way i can send it privately?

Comment: @alexdavies: Sorry, I'm not available to do that; you'll have to continue your debugging efforts. I would strongly recommend going back to the simple way and then figuring out what it was that was mis-observed. Also, whatever you do, **don't** use `alert` for this (or any other kind of debugging).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder from what I understand, the script adds script elements to the document head. The browser will not immediately execute the scripts until it regains control and (b) the injected script+src do not guarantee execution order.

Comment: @SalmanA: Again, in the async path, the OP is adding one script to the head, then waiting for onload on that script (which doesn't fire until it's loaded) before adding the next. At least, that's my read of the code. If you have a specific part of it you can point to (not the sync path, the async path) that adds more than one without waiting for the previous one, please point it out specifically. (Although frankly, I think it's a waste of your time and mine to continue on this, I think it's largely based on an observational error, from the comment about sequential script tags above.)

Comment: @SalmanA  ok, the sequential adding of files in a replicate of the way the files would be loaded but from the debug results why the different way of loading this script and what do you advice I do to get my desired result without any glitches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look in to using something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) - it will allow you do explicitly define modules that rely on other modules so you can always deterministically require all your code in the right order.

Comment: This is a *comment* (potentially a useful one), not an answer. The answer to "Why doesn't my code work?" is not "Use this library."

Comment: Thanks for the tip @T.J.Crowder :-)

Comment: Requirejs.js is a great Library, easy to learn straight forward and gives me the control I need. Thanks man! Not a solution but a solution if you know what I mean bra!